# Match an optional string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a regex pattern in string `processor (revision V00) with` using pattern `^processor +[\S]+ [\S]+ with` . I want the `(revision V00)` to be optional as it may not be present everytime in the string.

I tried using `^processor +(?:([\S]+ [\S]))+ with` but its not working

Comment: You can match an optional part between parenthesis `^processor(?: \([^()]*\))?` https://regex101.com/r/bh9ugD/1